# Correlating continuations in .NET Async

Tags: .net, async-await

In .NET asynchronous programming, I am looking for some correlation data that will be consistent throughout all of my asynchronous tasks that have the same root origination.  At the simplest level, I want in my logging to log this correlation identifier so I can quickly see an asynchronous "thread" of activity.

The correlation data I am looking for would be such that in the following code, the exception in TestCorrelation() would never be thrown:

```
private T _correlation;

private void TestCorrelation(T correlation)
{
   if (correlation != _correlation) throw new Exception("Ain't it");
}

public async Task MyMethod()
{
    _correlation = someCorrelator;

    await MyMethod2();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        TestCorrelation(someCorrelator);
    });
}

public async Task MyMethod2()
{
    TestCorrelation(someCorrelator);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        TestCorrelation(someCorrelator);
    });
}
```

Is there anything built into the asynchronous programming (such as a property of Task) that will give me such a correlation?

Comment: You can use `LogicalCallContext` for this, but you have to be careful with it. For details, see [Stephen Cleary's article *Implicit Async Context ("AsyncLocal")*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).

Comment: @svick, that is exactly what I need.  Thanks.  If you want to post an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MikeJansen If he doesn't please do it yourself so people know there's an answer here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @svick noted, you can use `LogicalCallContext`. However, there are two important limitations:

1. It will **only** work correctly on the .NET 4.5 full framework. No support for WinStore, .NET 4.0 (even if you install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`), etc. On some frameworks (notably .NET 4.0), the code will compmile just fine *but will not work correctly*.
2. You can **only** store immutable data. If you have complex data to store, you may find the [immutable collections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable) helpful. I use `ImmutableStack` in my [AsyncDiagnostics project](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncDiagnostics).

I have the full details [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).

Comment: Thank you @Stephen.  Your blog post was very helpful.  Even without copy-on-write, the logical call context could be used to simulate a "thread" name or ID, just without the ability to track forks.

Comment: Sort of. It could be used to track a linear logical call stack. It's not thread-specific; it will cross threads as necessary (e.g., it'll inherit "into" a `Task.Run`).